# How to add a column with conditions on another Dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Motivation: I want to check if customers have bought anything during 2 months since first purchase. (retention)

Resources: I have 2 tables:

1. Buy date, ID and purchase code
2. Id and first day he bought

Sample data:

```
Table1
    Date          ID    Purchase_code
 2019-01-01        1    AQT1
 2019-01-02        1    TRR1
 2019-03-01        1    QTD1

 2019-02-01        2    IGJ5
 2019-02-05        2    ILW2
 2019-02-20        2    WET2
 2019-02-28        2    POY6

Table 2
ID   First_Buy_Date
1     2019-01-01 
2     2019-02-01
```

The expected result:

```
ID       First_login_date      Retention    Frequency_buy_at_first_month
 1         2019-01-01              1                      2
 2         2019-02-01              0                      4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First convert columns to datetimes if necessary, then add first days by [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and create new columns by compare with [`Series.le`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.le.html) or [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html) and converting to integers:

```
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])
df2['First_Buy_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['First_Buy_Date'])

df = df1.merge(df2, on='ID', how='left')
df['Retention'] = (df['First_Buy_Date'].add(pd.DateOffset(months=2))
                                       .le(df['Date'])
                                       .astype(int))
df['Frequency_buy_at_first_month'] = (df['First_Buy_Date'].add(pd.DateOffset(months=1))
                                                          .gt(df['Date'])
                                                          .astype(int))
```

Last aggregate by [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) and `max` (if need only `0` or `1` output) and `sum` for count values:

```
df1 = (df.groupby(['ID','First_Buy_Date'], as_index=False)
         .agg({'Retention':'max', 'Frequency_buy_at_first_month':'sum'}))
print (df1)
   ID First_Buy_Date  Retention  Frequency_buy_at_first_month
0   1     2019-01-01          1                             2
1   2     2019-02-01          0                             4
```